# .NET and Multivalue D3

Tags: .net, database, multivalue

I read this forum for years, but this is the first question that I made here, I use a Multivalue DataBase with D3, I want to know how which its the best way to connect with Multivalue database from .net application, I want to get information for D3 (READ, WRITE, UPDATE) with .net application.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for posting a question on SO. As a recommendation, for this post, and all future ones, it's in your best interest to include as much information, examples, links, "what you've tried", etc, regarding your current issue. Meaning, what "type" of .NET app  are you referring to? What "connection" types are you questioning (refers back to what you've investigated on your behalf)? How often are you needing to use CRUD against this DB? Threads, dataset examples, etc. Be specific, otherwise you won't receive many answers and/or comments. SO is all about "you've put in research and debug time"

Answer (score 0):

MV Connect will let you create RESTFul Web Services written in MV Basic on any Multivalue System. You can then use any client you want as your front end. I work for Zumasys and I have created many services which are being used by Angular, Vue and .net.